# why is array scanning 1 extra element than specified in C

Tags: c, arrays

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekbgM.png<br/)

Problem: I am scanning and printing the two array using for loop.While scanning 1st array,it scans 1 extra element than specified size for eg. if array size is 5 it scans 6 element and while scanning 2nd array,it scans 1 less element than array size.
 Extra scanned element of 1st array gets printed as first element of second array which i tried to show in screenshot of Output

***note:*** **Complied and run in Dev Cpp v4.9.9.2**

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int i,arr1[10],arr2[10],num;
printf("no of elements to be enterd in array\t");
scanf("%d",&num);
printf("enter elements for 1st array\n");
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
                  scanf("%d\n",&arr1[i]);
}
printf("\nOutput for 1st array\n\n");
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
                  printf("%d\t",arr1[i]);
}

printf("\n\nenter elements for 2nd array\n");
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
                  scanf("\n%d",&arr2[i]);
}
printf("Output for 2nd array\n\n");
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
                  printf("%d\t",arr2[i]);
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any time code has trouble with `scanf()`, check the return value of `scanf()`.  Even if code does not have trouble, good code does check the return value of all input functions.

Comment: @Sanjeet mark the answer if your problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

> here, while in the loop of scanning numbers for arrays don't give \n
>   after or before %d in scanf that'd solve the problem..try this instead

```
 scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all because of the way you are using scanf.
change all of then to something like the following:

```
scanf(" %d",&arr1[i]);
```

That is: space before, nothing after (no space after, no "\n" no "\t" none of this).

Comment: `" %d"` is effectively the same as `"%d"`.  `"%d"` by itself consumes leading white-space like ``"  "``

Comment: @chux agree, anyway a leading space can never do harm, unlike a trailing one; and I have some preference to make it explicit.